# What happens if I remove paint from a hat?

Tags: team-fortress-2

With the October 6th 2010 patch, Team Fortress 2 added the possibility to remove paint from painted hats.

But if I remove the paint from a hat, is it simply washed out and lost, or will I get my color tinge/paint bucket back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing paint from a hat will not "reimburse" you with a paint can.